# Match regex pattern multiple times

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will match a given pattern between 2 and unlimited times.  Effectively I'm just trying to combine multiple line breaks in to one, if any exist at all.

Sample input:

```
<br><br>
<br>
ABC
<br>
<br>
```

Expected output:

```
<br>
ABC
<br>
```

If the regex was run on the above output then I would expect to see the exact same output.

There could be any amount of whitespace between the `<br>` tags.

What I've tried:

```php
$html = preg_replace('/(?:<br>\s?){2,}/s', null, $html);
```

Comment: If you don't have to bother with Windows-created files (with line terminator `\r\n`), consider replacing matches of `/\n{2,}/` with `\n` or `/\n(?=\n)/` with an empty string (both with the multiline flag set) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look for a `<br>` followed by optional space characters 2 or more times and replace with `<br>`:

```
$html = preg_replace('/(<br>\s*){2,}/', '<br>', $html);
```

You might replace with `"<br>\n"` if you want.